Mongoose Time Issue
I am facing an issue with my Mongoose query to retrieve available rooms based on a specified date range,
I have an API endpoint designed to fetch rooms available between two dates. When I make a GET request using the following URL:
http://localhost:3000/api/room/getAllAvailableRoomsByDate?startDate=2024-10-10&endDate=2024-10-14

But I am getting wrong date output
{
    "type": true,
    "data": [
        {
            "_id": "670715e03b5b98f2ceba72f4",
            "number": "104",
            "type": "suite",
            "price": 300,
            "quantity": 1,
            "isAvailable": true,
            "availableDates": [
                {
                    "start": "2024-10-10T00:00:00.000Z",
                    "end": "2024-10-17T00:00:00.000Z",
                    "_id": "670716063b5b98f2ceba72f7"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "message": "All rooms fetched"

}
Here is my endpoint. What is the issue I couldn't solve ?
  static async getAllAvailableRoomsByDate(req, res) {
    try {
      const { startDate, endDate } = req.query;

      if (!startDate || !endDate) {
        return res.status(400).json({ success: false, message: 'Both start date and end date are required' });
      }

      const start = new Date(startDate);
      const end = new Date(endDate);

      if (isNaN(start.getTime()) || isNaN(end.getTime())) {
        return res.status(400).json({ success: false, message: 'Invalid date format' });
      }

      if (start >= end) {
        return res.status(400).json({ success: false, message: 'End date must be after start date' });
      }

      console.log('Query dates:', start, end);

      const availableRooms = await Room.find({
        availableDates: {
          $elemMatch: {
            start: { $lte: end },
            end: { $gte: start }
          }
        }
      });


      return { type: true, data: availableRooms, message: 'All rooms fetched' }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      return { type: false, message: 'An error occurred getting all rooms' };
    }
  }

This is my mongoDb data modelling
const roomSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  number: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
  type: { type: String, enum: ['basic', 'premium', 'suite'], required: true },
  price: { type: Number, required: true },
  quantity: { type: Number, required: true, default: 1 },
  isAvailable: { type: Boolean, default: true },
  availableDates: [{ start: Date, end: Date }]

})


What do you mean by "I am getting wrong date output"?

isNaN is pointless on a function which always returns a number.

The query is looking for anything with an end after the requested start and that starts before the requested end.  The document you show meets that criteria, so what is the problem?
